# Problema con el comportamiento de un dropdown

Tags: html, bootstrap, vistas

Necesito ayuda con este dropddown ya que me funciona normal con las propiedades responsive definidas para los pcs con px superiores a 1400. Pero con los menores, el dropdown en lugar de desplegar la lista hacia abajo lo hace hacia la derecha. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown text-center">
  <div class="btn-group flex-column">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light btn-sm my-auto" 
      href="#categorias">Categorías</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn text-light dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" 
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu flex-column" id="categoriasDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Por favor, necesito ayuda. Se los agradecería mucho.

--- EDITADO ---

Ahora quedó así:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown text-center">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light btn-sm" 
      href="#categorias">Categorías</a>
      <div class="flex-column">
        <button type="button" class="btn text-light dropdown-toggle 
        dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
        expanded="false">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu flex-column">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
          </li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Hola, primero que nada te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: el codigo que has compartido es el sugerido por bootstrap ... que has intentado tu para resolver el problema???

Comment: Sí, es de bootstrap 5. Y he intentado separar el botón que me despliega la lista y la lista, y cuando se despliega el ancla categorías se baja junto a la lista.

Comment: Nada, la sigue desplegando a la derecha

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: mmm ok, junto con la ultima modificacion agrega esto:  `<div class="btn-group d-flex flex-column">` es el wrapper del boton con eso deberia solucionarce

Comment: si eso no funciona ya no se que hacer XD

Comment: Jajajajaja no funcionó. Aunque me puse a inventar y ya no lo corre a la derecha, pero la cosa es que mueve el ancla categorías a la izquierda.

Comment: no lo veo XD ... metelo mejor en un fdle js

Comment: Ya lo edité jajajaja

Comment: Como es HTML + CSS + JS, podés agregar un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). De hacerlo, no olvides agregar el CSS y el JS de Bootstrap, haciendo clic en _Agregar librería externa_, situado a la izquierda de la pantalla.

Answer (score -1):

intenta forzar el despliegue con la clase `dropdown-menu-end` de la siguiente manera:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu flex-column dropdown-menu-end" id="categoriasDropdown">
```